# Spring Application to Spring boot Migration -"No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa

Am migrating Spring application to spring boot.Unable to run spring boot boot application its showing an error given below

```
   ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataAccessService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at com.app.services.api.ServiceMain.main(ServiceMain.java:27)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:575)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:697)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    ... 21 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.766 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-23T03:43:31-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 54M/456M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project XERService: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'dataAccessService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Porm.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>X</groupId>
        <artifactId>X</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>

        <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version> <relativePath/> -->
    </parent>
    <name>service</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- 2.1.3.RELEASE -->
        <springframework.boot.version>2.1.7.RELEASE</springframework.boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn3</artifactId>
            <version>${jconn3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsr311-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId> <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.boot.version}</version>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

DataAccessService

```
@Repository

public class DataAccessService
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DataAccessService.class);

    private static final String DEFAULT_HOSTNAME = "localhost";

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="SIRCCPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

usage of DataAccessService

```
@Configuration
public class A{
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context = null;
public static DataAccessService dataAccessService;
 private static void init(boolean isHttps)
    {
  dataAccessService = (DataAccessService) context .getBean("DataAccessService");
   }
}
```

another place its is autowired using @autowire

pom.xml dependency hierarchy

[image]

I cant find the exact the reason for this bug.did i miss anything in pom.xml, or its a version issue?
please suggest the solution

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="SIRCCPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/queries.xml</mapping-file> 
        <class></class>        
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=ERROR, Tool=ERROR" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="sybase" />
            <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: Do you have any service class name **DataAccessService**?
Look at the error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataAccessService' `

Comment: Yes i have.annotated as @Repository

Comment: Have you used this class in anywhere else, I mean have you `autowired` anywhere ?

Comment: public static DataAccessService dataAccessService;                
 dataAccessService = (DataAccessService) localDataAccessContext.getBean("DataAccessService");    using like this

Comment: Can you post that class and other class where you are calling `dataAccessService`

Comment: can u please check the updated question

Comment: You haven't posted your `DataAccessService`. Please post that also.

Comment: Can you post your project in github?

Comment: You have a jar file conflict.

Comment: i have resolved the resource.still getting the error

Comment: updated the question @AvijitBarua